# how to store entire grid view into one single row of table in a database asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

i have a grid view shopping cart in my application. the datasource of gridview is session as datatable.. i have no problem in shopping cart. my cart is perfectly the way i want it.. now my problem is that on PLACEORDER button click i want to export this gridview details into database like

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Orderid  |  Orderdate    | products            | amount      | username
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
xxx      |  datetime.now |all products in cart | total amount| currentuser
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

single row in the order table should contain all the details about the order that a user places
[image: shoppingcart gridview]

Now my question is it possible to do it ? if yes how ? please explain. i m short of time .. thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the entire shopping cart in one row, not one cell?

Comment: yes.. that is what i want to do.

Comment: Are you trying to merge multiple products on an order into one row in a database table?  This breaks normalization.  In your database you should have an order header table linked to an order line table with product by product details.

Comment: honesty i dont know how order works. so far my products are in cart. cart has datasource a session variable. i have to place this order in data base from where admin can access it and products can be sent to the user that placed order..

Comment: A single row should not contain all the details about the order. That violates 1NF. You should not store more than 1 piece of information in a single intersection. You need two tables for this as @MichaelMcGriff suggested above.

Comment: what if i make an entirely new  order table with no relation with my product table ? then i dont think any normalization rule is voilated?

Comment: Look for master-detail examples. Master will be your order(DB table) and details(DB table with foreign key to Orders table)  - products added to order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second table, that would have 3 columns:
1. Your primary key for the table
2. OrderId (a foreign key to your order table)
3. The product or the productId.

Then you can select all the products with a given OrderId to see what was ordered on that order. This also allows you to count products sold and a bunch of other reporting if needed.

The wrong way to do it would be to store it in the same table as a long string. This allows no reporting, forces you to parse it in your code, ruins all scalability... It is a bad solution don't do it.

Comment: thankyou so much.. you cleared my doubt. i was trying to it the wrong way.